# Как перерисовать ListView после изменения списка?

Tags: java, android

Есть ListView. В OnCreate нахожу его.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvBase);
```

Там же создаю список list4lv и прописываю его в адаптере

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items, list4lv);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

В процессе работы список list4lv меняется и надо чтобы на экране ListView поменялся (перерисовался) соответственно. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У адаптера есть такой метод `notifyDataSetChanged()`, который обновляет список. Его нужно вызывать каждый раз, когда данные изменяются:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```